# Mute Youtube embeded videos on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

Hello I'm using the following code to mute embedded youtube video,
It works fine on chrome but not on **FIREFOX**

```
<iframe id='video_player' class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?wmode=opaque&autohide=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1' frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script>
var mp = iframe.getElementById('video_player');
mp.setVolume(0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the method for the HTML Audio/Video DOM `.volume`

It's usage would be something, such as:

```
var mp = document.getElementById('video_player');
mp.volume = 0; // 0%
```

Comment: Thank you your modification works fine on chrome but also didn't work on firefox